# IconElement to display ①

Tags: xaml, uwp, windows-10, uwp-xaml

I want to use IconElement to display ①.
I cannot find it in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/style/segoe-ui-symbol-font 
How can I do it?

Thanks
Scott

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest built-in icons are from [`SymbolIcon`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.symbol) with intellisense support when you write them.

```
<SymbolIcon Symbol="Help" />
```

---

Then you have [`FontIcon`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.fonticon) but you will need to know what to put in `Glyph`. I normally find them from **Character Map** on Windows 10.

```
<FontIcon Foreground="Wheat" 
          FontFamily="Candara" Glyph="&#x03A3;" />
<FontIcon Foreground="Wheat" 
          FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" Glyph="&#xE00B;" />
```

---

You can also replace `FontIcon` with `TextBlock`.

```
<TextBlock Foreground="Wheat" 
           Text="&#xE001;" FontFamily="Segoe UI Symbol" />
```

---

### Update

Man... I just realized you were looking for a specific icon. It can be found in *Segoe UI Symbol* from the **Character Map**.

```
<FontIcon Foreground="Wheat" 
              Glyph="&#x2460;" FontFamily="Segoe UI Symbol" />
```

[image]